# Refresh HTML select after updating options with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a `<select>` that updates with Ajax when it is clicked. However, if the number of `<option>`s when it is clicked is different from the number of `<option>`s after it is clicked, the dropdown doesn't expand/contract to accommodate the options. How do I refresh the `<select>` to make it accommodate the `<option>`s?

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates this: http://jsfiddle.net/q6qp4xLe/

```js
$('#t').click(function(){
   $(this).empty();
   for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
       $(this).append('<option>Another option</option>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id=t><option>Option</option></select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `mousedown` event instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/q6qp4xLe/2/

```
$('#t').on("mousedown", function(){
   $(this).empty();
   for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
       $(this).append('<option>Another option</option>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

using .mousedown as your event instead of .click fixed the issue for me. Or at least I think it added the functionality your requesting.